# Write a script that outputs filename and linenumber that contains certain text

Tags: bash, latex

How can I write a (bash) script that scans all the .tex files in a folder for occurence of `\todo`, and outputs the filename and linenumber where it occurs?

What I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
for texfile in *.tex ; do
  **Scan for \todo**
  **output $textfile$ , linenumber**
done
```

I want to be certain that my .tex files doesn't contain `\todo{sometext}` when I deliver them.

It doesn't have to be bash, I only chose that for simplicity. Grep etc would certainly be welcome.

Comment: What is "filenumber"? Number of matching files or inode or number of hard links?

Comment: Sorry, filenumber should be filename, I will edit it right away.

Comment: Okay, no problem.

Comment: Must it be bash? I would try with grep to find the todo's and pipe that though wc -l

Comment: It could be grep as well, yes.

Comment: Can the `\todo{}` span multiple lines? If not, it is trivial to remove them automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` can do this by itself, you can wrap it in a script if needed:

```
grep -nr '\todo' *.tex
```

`-r` for recursive
`-n` to display the line number in the file

By default, grep will show the line that contains the match.  For some formats, this can mean a lot of output.  If you want to constrain the output so that you only get the match and a few characters either side, use this:

```
egrep -nor '.{0,20}\\todo.{0,20}'  *.tex
```

The `-o` means "only display matching result", however, this would then just display `\todo`.  To get some context, we allow any number of characters up to 20 on either side of the match.  The `.` matches anything, and the `{0,20}` repeats this match up to 20 chars.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to not output the whole paragraph where \todo is?

Comment: @bjornasm See additions in answer.